# pandas: convert list to int64index

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a DataFrame `df` in pandas with rows 0 to 99 and I want to retain only those rows of `df` that are in a list `x`.

Suppose list `x` has some values like `[3, 10, 71]` based on some programming logic that can change.

If I then try to access `df[df.index[x],'SomeColName']` I usually get an error saying `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Int64Index'`.

How can I convert a `list` to to `Int64Index` type?

I am using Python 3.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to convert the list to an index here - if you want to access particular rows and columns you can use `iloc`:

```
df.iloc[[3, 10, 71], 'SomeColName']
```

This will return a view of your DataFrame at rows 3, 10 and 71 in the column 'SomeColName'.

If you want get rid of all your other rows and columns, you could reassign the name `df` to this view.

Writing `df[df.index[x],df.index[x]` actually tries to find two columns named `df.index[x]` and `'SomeColName'`. Since column names need to be hashable, an error is raised when Pandas looks for `df.index[x]` (index objects are mutable).

Comment: actually, in `df.loc[[3, 10, 71], 'SomeColName']` your answer returns me the values in `SomeColName` when the row is labelled as `3, 10, and 71` rather than rows `3, 10, and 71` per se

Comment: Ah, in that case you want `iloc` (and not `loc`) - I've edited.